# I cannot access the website through the internet when openvpn is enabled

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, openvpn

In the same server (windows server 2008 r2) we have dns, web server and openvpn. The server has a static IP address, which is used to access the website through the internet by the domain name.
At this point if I ping the result is the following, which is correct:

```
C:\>ping domain.com
Pinging domain.com [186.111.125.131] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 186.111.125.131: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=121
Reply from 186.111.125.131: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=121
Reply from 186.111.125.131: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=121
Reply from 186.111.125.131: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=121
```

But the problem begins when we start the openvpn, and when pinging again, it does not return the static IP address of the server, it returns the IP address assigned by openvpn:

```
C:\>ping domain.com
Pinging domain.com [10.5.4.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Request time out.
Request time out.
Request time out.
Request time out.
```

We have the static IP interface as preferred, and also with a metric lower than the openvpn TUN interface, but still we have the problem.

I also add that the openvpn network works correctly, only the problem arises when trying to access the website through the internet or ping, since it returns the IP address of the open vpn network (10.5.4.1) .

Openvpn server config:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
dh dh2048.pem
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
topology subnet
server 10.5.4.0 255.255.255.0
client-config-dir ccd
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
cipher AES-256-CBC
persist-key
persist-tun
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.5.4.1"
push "dhcp-option WINS 10.5.4.1"
status openvpn-status.log 5
status-version 2
log-append openvpn.log
verb 3  # verbose mode
keepalive 10 60
```

Openvpn client config:

```
client
float
dev tun
proto udp
remote domain.com 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert cliente1.crt
key cliente1.key
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-256-CBC
verb 3
```

I would like to know if someone can guide me to solve this problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pushed DNS to client in the server config file:

```
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.5.4.1"
```

Your client, while disconnected, is using its configured DNS servers, and they generally resolve domain.com to what you configured in a public DNS zone for domain.com.

But, when connected, OpenVPN on a client receives "dhcp-option DNS 10.5.4.1" from a server and reconfigures client resolving according to this directive, setting 10.5.4.1 as DNS server. This is the same as just specify "10.5.4.1" as DNS server on a client. So your client, when connected, uses 10.5.4.1 to resolve domain.com A query.

I can deduce that 10.5.4.1 itself resolves domain.com A query to 10.5.4.1 (and, it seems, this is AD DC for domain.com). This reply is what client should receive according to your configuration.

To change this, you have two options.

1. Remove this push option from a server configuration, or set up client to ignore what server pushes by adding relevant push-filter in client config. In this case, client will not get its DNS server changed, and will keep resolving domain.com from public DNS zone. But you will lose the ability to access systems behind VPN by name from the client, because 10.5.4.1 will not became a DNS server on a client, and in general you don't want to publish details of your internal zone to your public DNS.
2. Set up alternative DNS server, which will return everything like your 10.5.4.1, except for domain.com A query, to which it will return other value, 186.111.125.131 or what you want it to be. Then push that alternative DNS server address instead of 10.5.4.1. Not quite easy to do (you'll either need a sophisticated DNS software which could do substitution realtime, or set up simple DNS server and constantly keep domain DNS and alternative DNS in sync by hand).

As a side note, never ever give same domain name to your AD domain and to your web site. Better create a subdomain like corp.example.com and use that for AD, and build AD three and other "private" services under that. This will leave domain.com and all other sub.comain.com subdomains free to use for web sites or other "public" services.

AD always creates an A record with domain name pointing to AD DCs. This is needed for your computers to be able to connect via SMB to DC shares not only by concrete DC name, but also by just domain name. These shares are DFS replicated between DCs, where  group policies and other domain-wide stuff reside for domain computers to access. And because this name is still inside domain realm, such access is perfectly protected by Kerberos. So, if you going to use any of options suggested here, keep in mind, that your client will not be able to enter domain and use it, because its DNS configuration will be not what AD needs. Don't do this if you require this VPN client to be a domain computer.